# Project References a specific version of a nuget package but another gets deployed

Tags: nuget, microsoft-web-deploy

I have a dependency linked in my nuget for another package I use. See how the version is 106.13.0. However when i publish via web deploy it actually deploys 107.2.0 which has breaking changes in it cause the app to crash because of it. Why is webdeploy publishing a newer version than referenced? My nuget folder only contains 106.13 so i do not know where it is pulling the new DLL from.[image]

[image: nuget package]
[image]

EDIT: Referenced Assemblies
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What do your assembly references look like? This references a nuget, but deployment doesn't deploy nugets, but it deploys the dll file that is resolved during the build...

Comment: @jessehouwing see edit

Comment: What does the verbose msbuild log op the publish step say?